# Scrolling in not working after chrome and edge update, works fine in firefox. I am using elementor and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, scroll, elementor

I have used Elementor to build by webpage and it is not scrolling properly, while similar page is opening and scrolling smoothly in firefox

I tried some common solution posted on internet, like changing smoothscroll.js and installing jquery update

Answer (score 0):

depending on the version of Elementor it could be due to a conflict between some values (generated by Elementor itself) and the last version of Chrome.

Try updating Elementor (and Elementor Pro, if you have it) to the latest version.

I'd recommend doing a backup of your site before trying.